# Как освободить память, выделенную в статическом методе класса?

Tags: c++, winapi

Существует такой класс:

```
class process
{
    HANDLE hndl;
public:
    static HANDLE attach(char*, unsigned long = PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS);
};
```

В нём есть статический метод `attach`, при вызове которого добавляется сотня килобайтов к потреблению оперативной памяти, но после отработки освобождается лишь то, что я выделил при помощи `new`, `calloc` и `malloc`, и освободил при помощи `delete` и `free`, и почти всё что было добавлено при вызове метода не было освобождено, т.е. уже не используется и при этом висит в памяти. Можно как-нибудь освободить всё, что было выделено методом, включая память на его обслуживание, или нужно написать по-другому?

И ещё. Базу я не знаю, учусь по видеоурокам и своим экспериментам, так что приветствуются любые правки и замечания. Спасибо.

Проблемный код:

```
HANDLE game::attach(char* process, unsigned long access)
    {
        {

            HANDLE handle   = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
            PROCESSENTRY32* pentry = new PROCESSENTRY32;
            pentry->dwSize = 556;
            if (Process32First(handle, pentry))
            {

                void* ptr = calloc(256, 1);

                if (!CharToOemW(pentry->szExeFile, (char*)ptr))
                    return 0;

                if (!strcmp((char*)ptr, process))
                {

                    free(ptr);
                    goto opening;
                }
                while (Process32Next(handle, pentry))
                {
                    if (!CharToOemW(pentry->szExeFile, (char*)ptr))

                        return 0;
                    if (!strcmp((char*)ptr, process))
                    {
                        free(ptr);
                        goto opening;
                    }
                }
            }

        return 0;

    opening:

            CloseHandle(handle);
            handle = OpenProcess(access, 0, pentry->th32ProcessID);
            delete pentry;
            return handle;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `CloseHandle` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Я попробовал передать 0 и закрыть хендлы до возврата, но это не помогло. Совсем.

Comment: Память, о которой Вы говорите, под функции не выделяется. Для поиска утечек памяти (и ресурсов в общем) следует использовать программы, называемые *профилировщиками*. Список для Windows можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/413477/3240681).

Comment: Чтобы повторить проблему постарайтесь привести [mcve] в теле вопроса.

Comment: @SPNN13 "попробовал передать 0 и закрыть хендлы до возврата" - это никому ничего не говорит. Мы не видим Вашего кода и, несмотря на наши телепатические способности, не можем угадать где у Вас утекает память.

Comment: путём экспериментов я выяснил, что утечка происходит из-за этой строки: HANDLE handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
но я до последнего не подозревал её, и до сих пор не понимаю почему это так. Если её убрать, остальной механизм не оставляет ни одного лишнего байта

У меня есть подозрения, что утечка из-за того что я закрывая хендл, записываю новый в ту же переменную. Может из-за этого утечка?
В конце функции идёт это:
CloseHandle(handle);
handle = OpenProcess(access, 0, pentry->th32ProcessID);

Comment: @SPNN13 нет, не из-за этого

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Bp68AJWc
вот .cpp класса, у меня предположения кончились. может вы увидите что-то подозрительное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> я закрывая хендл, записываю новый в ту же переменную. Может из-за
>   этого утечка?

Hет, не из-за этого.

Вы где-то выходите из функции не закрыв `handle`.

> "Помылся - закрой душ!" (с)

*Update*

В Вашем коде несколько `return`-ов мимо вызова `CloseHandle`.

Comment: Чёрт. Точно! Спасибо! Как-то я об этом и не подумал.

Comment: @SPNN13 Пожалуйста. Вы не могли бы поместить Ваш код в вопрос - "в назидание народам древности"?

Comment: Совершенно не смешно.

Comment: @SPNN13 это из Венедикта Ерофеева

Comment: @SPNN13 Из pastebin Вы код убрали, так что теперь ссылка на него ведет в никуда. Я попросил Вас поместить проблемный код в вопрос, чтобы найденое решение было полезно не только Вам.

Comment: Ой, даже так.. я-то думал это намерение укусить меня за такую невнимательность <:D
Конечно, я не против чтоб кто-то учился на моей ошибке Х)
https://pastebin.com/ZRJ2dFM3

Comment: @SPNN13 "укусить" - ни в коем случае :). Я могу добавить код в вопрос, если Вы не возражаете, или Вы сами можете это сделать - ссылка "править" под вопросом.

Comment: Готово ^^
Остаётся надеяться что кто-то наткнётся на пост с этой же проблемой, и решит её быстрее чем я - не потратив на это всю светлую часть суток х)